# Validation of symbols in search textbox

Tags: c#

I experienced error when typing symbols in my search box. I already used the ajax tool to validate symbols like " ' / etc. ". With this, you are not allowed to type any symbols you declared to be invalid. What if I will search for a character or word that contains that symbol? For example, the name of the customer I want to search is O'Brien but how will I search if I am not allowed to type that symbol?

Comment: You wont be able to that's the point right? If you want to allow them to type in that name just allow that character.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to. That is why you have set that value as `invalid`. Remove the value from the `invalid` symbols and you will be able to.

If a symbol can be valid some of the time but not all of the time, it is probably better to allow it by default than block it. That way you are less likely to upset an end user.

If you are required to then you should handle the symbol in your code that processes the search.

Comment: I understand. But if I will remove the value in invalid, I will experience errors in my search box. Is it possible to prevent those kinds of errors?

Comment: I assume you are using some kind of database query, try the following : `string searchText = tbSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''");`. In SQL `'`s are used to declare values, you need to replace what is in the string effectively doubling up the value to allow SQL to understand it. Of course if you are not using SQL please let us know.

Comment: Not sure if that would work for SQL query from a string, would it be able to understand an escape character or would the SQL treat it incorrectly? I'm more used to VB than I am to C# unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, you're again right! :D But then it leaves on one thing to replace the string. As I have posted the code below

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit tricky. You should not allow user to add such stuff to the database I mean he should not be inserting any data while signing up, so that you don't have to worry about it later. If you want to let the users add these `special` characters then you must do the coding work while letting the user search for that name of whatever it is.

**Solution:**

If you are using `JavaScript` (`jQuery`) then you can try out this:

What you will do here, is:

1. First get the input value.
2. Replace `'` character will `` (empty).
3. Then check whether that was the only character placed.

Code is as follows:

```
if($('#input-id').val().replace("'", "") == "") { // only quote was written
   $('#input-id').val(''); // and tell him to write a name..
} else {
   // search for name..
}
```

Secondly I will assume you are talking about SQL Injection, because using `'` in SQL Select clause of `LIKE` will break the Query, so I will first try to tell you either save the name without these characters or try to change them into some other format. Here http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Otherwise, try to learn about SQL Injections.

**Ajax:**

You said you are using Ajax, so if you are using `ASP.NET`. You can use this:

```
var data = Request["data"];
data.ToString().Replace("'", "");
if(data == "") {
   // tell him to behave!
} else {
   // search for name..
}
```

This is the easiest way to get rid of these characters without using any plugin.

its just `JavaScript`.

Comment: Just to hopefully be a little more clear, I believe the Ajax Tool he was referring to was [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx)

Comment: Yes, might be! But he never told about any tool hehehe..:)

Comment: Well he mentioned ajax tool, `I already used the ajax tool to validate symbols like " ' / etc. "` to me that seemed more like the control toolkit rather than simple ajax, but I suppose I could be wrong :)

Comment: Nah, you're right brother! I missed the tool thing. I just saw the `ajax`.